# R: arrow with installing arrow on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I tried to install {arrow} using `install.packages("arrow")` but I am getting the following error

```r
In file included from array.cpp:18:0:
./arrow_types.h:198:10: fatal error: parquet/arrow/reader.h: No such file or directory
```

I am using R 3.6.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be "hidden" in plain sight in the [README doc](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/r)

I have to install `libparquet-dev` via

```sh
sudo apt-get install libparquet-dev
```

then it works

Comment: Quick note: this has changed with more recent arrow releases. It should "just work". See the install vignette here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow/vignettes/install.html